# I am trying to print NSE india site table on google spread sheet but I am not able to get it

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api, spread

I am trying to print NSE india site table on google spread sheet but I am not able to get it.
The prbolem I am facing in range functions what exaclty paramters I need to pass to get this table on google spreadsheet?

Below is my code.

```
var cellFunction = '=IMPORTHTML("https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?symbolCode=-9999&symbol=BANKNIFTY&symbol=BANKNIFTY&instrument=OPTIDX&date=-&segmentLink=17&segmentLink=17","table")';
sheetName.getRange('1','23','80','80').setValue(cellFunction);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`.setFormula`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula) instead of [`.setValue`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) if you want to set the cell content to a formula.

You also only need to insert the formula into a single cell - it will automatically expand the data in the table in the adjacant cells.

Try replacing

```
sheetName.getRange('1','23','80','80').setValue(cellFunction);
```

with

```
sheetName.getRange(1, 1).setFormula(cellFunction);
```

A full working example would be:

```
function insertFormula() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1); // inserts formula into A1
  range.setFormula('=IMPORTHTML("https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?symbolCode=-9999&symbol=BANKNIFTY&symbol=BANKNIFTY&instrument=OPTIDX&date=-&segmentLink=17&segmentLink=17";"table")');
}
```

Comment: @PKInception there must be enough free cells to insert the table, try it with an empty sheet.